# How to add new sheet in an existing workbook?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to create a new sheet using c# using the code below. My excel file has already 2 sheets and the problem is adding a third one. However the program crashes in the line where I create the `var newS`. Can someone please explain why?

I know for sure that the problem is not before the creation of `newS` because I've been debugging the code and it works perfectly fine without the last 2 lines.

```cs
wbs= excel.Workbooks;
wb=wbs.Open(Path.Combine(App.Domain.BaseDiretory, template_path, template_filename)) 

Excel.Sheets shs=wb.Sheets;

Excel.Worksheet sh=shs[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
//code not relevant between these lines
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(sh);

Excel.Worksheet sh=shs[2] as Excel.Worksheet;
//code not relevant between these lines
Marshall.ReleaseComObject(sh);

var newS=(Excel.Worksheet)shs.Add(shs[3], Type.missing, Type.missing, Type.missing);

newS.name="1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shs.Add(shs[3], Type.missing, Type.missing, Type.missing);` does not look a valid call as you said you have two sheets in your workbook. You are attempting to add new sheet before *third* one which does not exist. Refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add).

> `Before` - Optional - Variant - An object that specifies the sheet before which the new sheet is added.

All parameters are optional; may be you should simply pass `Type.Missing` instead of `shs[3]`. New sheet will be added before the active sheet.

> If Before and After are both omitted, the new sheet is inserted before the active sheet.

Alternatively, replace the call to represent the sheet that exists.